# Does the output count as one layer?

Tags: deep-learning

In neutral network, when talking about layers, does the output count as one layer? It seems some people count, and others don't, based on my readings. For example, the author says this is a 2 layer network. Shouldn't at least input, hidden, and output be 3 layers?

The article is here: http://karpathy.github.io/2016/05/31/rl/.

[image]

Comment: I find it confusing too but I notice people mostly mention as "I use x amount of hidden layers with [x,y,x] nodes"

Comment: How many layers do you think this is?

Comment: Well... As you mentioned One input layer , 1 hidden layer and one output layer. By the definition of layer I would say total 3. But for not confusing people I would just say 1 hidden layer

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your definition it counts. You could define it as a 1 layer network, but most people I talk to would say this is a 3 layer network. The definition that sticks is the one most people use. Programmatically this is aslo written as three layers in Keras or any other framework.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the people who use the term, but usually one is interested in the number of layers which have weights. (As I think of the weights being in between the layers this is a bit strange, but anyway).

From this logic, the network above is a 2-layer network. 2 weight/learned layers.

You could also say the network has one hidden layer (and one input and one output layer).